# Sharing common navigationOptions across screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

so I'm having trouble setting global header styles across multiple screens in my React Native Project.

Ive followed the steps outlined in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html but im getting a syntax error every time I try to run it.

All im doing is setting the header background color and the tint for the button and header.

Ive attached my code below....if anyone can point to me what it is I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
[import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import {View,Text,StyleSheet,Platform,TouchableOpacity,Image,StatusBar} from 'react-native';

import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from '../screens/ProfileScreen';
import CharityScreen from '../screens/CharityScreen';
import RunScreen from '../screens/RunScreen';

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen
  },
  Charity: {
    screen: CharityScreen
  },
  Run: {
    screen: RunScreen
  }

});

const StackNav = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen
  },
  DrawerNav: {
    screen: DrawerNavigator
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#2b3991',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff'
    },
  },
});

export default StackNav;][1]
```

Error Message:

error: bundling failed: SyntaxError in C:\Users\Michal\apps\run\src\nav\rootnav.js: C:/Users/Michal/apps/run/src/nav/rootnav.js: Unexpected token (35:4)
  33 |   DrawerNav: {
  34 |     screen: DrawerNavigator,

> 35 |     {
>        |     ^
>     36 |       navigationOptions: {
>     37 |         headerStyle: {
>     38 |           backgroundColor: '#2b3991',

Comment: please provide error message

Comment: @JayThummar I just added the error code - it says its a syntax error?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try designing the navigator like below:-

const StackNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: LoginScreen,
    DrawerNav: DrawerNavigator,
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#2b3991',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff'
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the issue. Im assuming the issue was the closing bracket.

Comment: Yes.. the screens need to be an object of the navigator. and the navigation options need to be an another object

Answer (score 0):

Try this code because there is a syntext error  at navigationOptions  in your code

```
const StackNav = createStackNavigator({
   Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen
   },
   DrawerNav: {
   screen: DrawerNavigator
  },
}, 
{
 navigationOptions: {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#2b3991',
  },
  headerTintColor: '#fff'
 },
  }, 
);
```

Comment: and aside from blank white space I dont see any difference in our code.

Comment: i have edited the answer try it    there is a syntext error  at navigationOptions  in your code

Comment: Thanks for your help.....@prernagupta's solution worked. Im assuming it was the brackets that surrounded the screens that caused the error....

Comment: yes it is the problem so i have edited the answer and try another editor like VS Code and use snipest to ride out from this syntex problem